# Android Studio - Top Level Exception - Support Lib via maven

Tags: android, maven, amazon-web-services, android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.0

i'm working with android studio and i have an issue... i import 2 libraries (facebook SDK and Aws) that both use and import the android support v4 libs, doing that gradle can't compile anything giving a bad top-level exception (dexDebug).
In others answer i saw that i can solve this situation in 2 ways, removing one of the libs (but i can't because i need both) or using the "multipledex = true" in build.gradle that give me another error for the length of the command.

So, what i should do? Shall i stop using AS and go back to Eclipse? Or anybody have a solution?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import the support library by copying its jar as you used to in Eclipse. In Gradle, access it via its Maven coordinates and the build system will ensure that only one copy gets linked into your project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:X.X.X'
}
```

where `X.X.X` is the right version number for your SDK installation. If you manage the dependency via **Project Structure > (your module) > Dependencies > + > Library dependency** it will help you get the version number right.